# Linq Select items that are mapped as many-to-many?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to build a select query to a table while only contains concatenated Primary Key values and no attributes. I managed to get the select query alright, but I can't quite figure out how to get the select statement. Basically I am trying to get a list of DegreeID's, from the DegreeRelationship table, (which is mapped and not an entity) from a ProgramID in DiplomaCertificate entity. Then I want to get the Degree name as well.

My context with the mapped tables looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Degree>()
                .HasMany(e => e.DiplomaCertificates)
                .WithMany(e => e.Degrees)
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("DegreeRelationship").MapLeftKey("DegreeID").MapRightKey("ProgramID"));
```

and basically, I am trying to put values into this object:

```
public class DegreeRelationshipInfo
    {
        public int ProgramID { get; set; }
        public int DegreeID { get; set; }
        public string LinkedProgramName { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying a method something like this, but I am not sure how to write this exactly (and this is completely wrong):

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
        public List<DegreeRelationshipInfo> Select_DegRel(int programID)
        {
            using (Pathway_Model context = new Pathway_Model())
            {
                var results = from data in context.Degrees
                              where data.DiplomaCertificates.Where(x => x.ProgramID == programID)
                              select new DegreeRelationshipInfo
                              {
                                  ProgramID = data.ProgramID,
                                  // no idea how to get this value.... 
                              };
                return results.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Select the entities by `SelectMany` and collect their key values:

```
from data in context.Degrees
from cert in data.DiplomaCertificates
select new DegreeRelationshipInfo
{
    ProgramID = data.ProgramID,
    DegreeID = cert.DegreeID,
    LinkedProgramName = data.Name // I guess...
}
```

This `from - from` construction is compiled into `SelectMany`, but the syntax is much better readable.